# How could I have access to content of csv file after upload with Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, csv

I have wrote a very simple csv upload function with angular-file-upload. The code is as following. I think I need to access the content of the file I upload. I need to get the first several rows of csv to show as the preview of the file. Could I know how to get the data?

```
  app.controller('reporting.importexternaldata.controllers.main', [
            '$scope',
        'FileUploader',
        function ($scope, FileUploader) {
            console.log('hahahahahaah');

            var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
                autoUpload: false,
                queueLimit: 1,
                filters: [{
                    name: 'csvOnly',
                    fn: function(item) {
                        console.log('in filter, file type (item.type) is: ' + item.type);
                        console.info('size: ' + item.size);
                        return true;
                    }
                }]
            });
       }
]);
```

html:

```
<div>
        <h2> Choose a csv file </h2>
        <input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" accept=".csv" />
    </div>
    <p>Queue length: {{ uploader.queue.length }}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
        <h2>{{ item.file.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ item._file}}</p>
    </div>
```

in `<p>{{ item._file}}</p>`, I expect to have the preview of the first 5 rows of the csv. But I do not know how to access the data, could I know how?